# Force AWS SSM to communicate via FQDN rather than IP address?

Tags: aws-ssm

The https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html website lists all of the SSM endpoints that need to be whitelisted over port 443/tcp (https) in order for AWS SSM agents to communicate; however, after about 2-3 weeks of troubleshooting, I just came to the conclusion that AWS SSM does not actually communicate via FQDN, which causes problems for proxies that only whitelist FQDNs and not IP addresses.

Since the IP addresses of thoes FQDNs don't point back to those FQDNs, this leaves the AWS SSM tool broken in the particular environment I'm using it.

Is there a way to either "force" AWS SSM to use FQDNs when communicating outbound?

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not use or allow FQDNs in security groups or routing unless you are remaining on their network (AWS service to AWS service communication). You must use IPv4 or IPv6 addresses in all other cases.

[This AWS article is good](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-systems-manager-vpc-endpoints/), but I have found that the SSM Messages and EC2 Messages endpoints are also required, [which is addressed here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-create-vpc.html).

Basically, you need to create 3 VPC endpoints (SSM, SSM Messages, and EC2 Messages) and route the 443 traffic to them while allowing the traffic on the affected security groups, route tables and NACLs. This has the advantage of not having the traffic leave AWS' networks and the traffic will not be affected by your firewalls/proxies in most architectures. Beware that the AWS documentation is not good and conflicts with itself, as shown in the 2 articles linked here.